logstash- SQL_LAST_VALUE cant be changed
i have Logstash that read database table and pass the read data to Elasticsearch and Kafka ,,,,, im using OpenShift , this pod scheduled run everyday @ 10:00 pm to be run  .... this pod is working fine for about month ... im tracking the data from table  using last_sql_value ,,,, after many days successful work the last_sql_value freeze in one value and not updated to the last value in table  and the data stopped read from database and passed to elastic and  kafka but the logstash is running everyday but the last_sql_value not changed also there is no any error in the logs .,... please help
try to find a solution for my problem
